Probability for a quantum many particle system of temperature $T$ to be found at temperature $T'$
Suppose we have a system of $N$ particles (let's postpone the question re statistics) in thermal equilibrium, described via a density operator
$$ \rho_\beta = Z^{-1} e^{-\beta H} $$
$$ Z = \text{tr} \, e^{-\beta H} = \sum_n e^{-\beta E_n} $$
where $H$ ist the $N$-particle Hamiltonian, $\beta = (k_\text{B} T)^{-1}$ and $n$ labels the energy eigenstates.
I wonder how one can formulate the following questions mathematically:

what is the probability to find this system in a state that looks like a thermal state with temperature $T^\prime \neq T$?

what is the probability to find this system in a state within the energy interval $[E, E + \Delta E]$?


For the first question my guess would simply be
$$ p_{\beta^\prime} = \text{tr} \, ( \rho_\beta \, \rho_{\beta^\prime} ) $$
For the second question I would propose to evaluate
$$ A_{E, E + \Delta E} = \int_{E}^{E + \Delta} d\epsilon \, \delta(\epsilon - H) $$
$$ p_{E, E + \Delta E} = \text{tr} \, ( \rho_\beta \, A_{E, E + \Delta E} ) = Z^{-1} \sum_{n : \, E_n \in [E, E + \Delta E]} e^{-\beta E_n} $$

The first question does not make sense in the usual framework. Temperature is regarded as a macroscopic property/parameter. Specifying the temperature (in the canonical ensemble) fixes the average energy and vice versa; you wouldn't ask "what is the probability to find a certain average energy" either. Both are properties/parameters of the distribution, the density operator.

...but if you want to find the probability that a post-measurement outcome state is  a density matrix of a thermal state with different temperature (say, on a formal level), you can try to find a projection operator $P$ such that $P\rho(\beta)P\sim \rho(\beta^\prime)$; then the probability is just given by the Born rule.

The first answer – that the question does not make sense at the formal level – is not surprising; but in practice it makes sense practically, e.g. by measuring the temperature T' in a small volume given the average temperature in a larger one.

Equilibrium thermodynamics assumes that temperature is everywhere the same (in the system, of course). Also, are you sure you would describe such a measurement with the projection valued measure?

In the second comment you are essentially saying that my proposal to use the expectation value of $\rho^\prime$ directly is wrong (but that I have to find an appropriate projector which is then to be used in the Born rule). I am wondering if this makes sense.

Well, yes, according to the "usual" rules of quantum mechanics, to describe probability of measurement outcomes, you have to use projections (this can be generalized, though); then you can speak of post-measurement states, which is how I read your question. I don't know, though, if such a $P$ exists, but I haven't tried it. Your attempt does not make much sense to me. Do all probabilities for all possible "measurement outcomes" add to one, for example?

I think I will go for the second option using the energy expectation value. I have less doubts with that, just a technical problem (I will post a second question)

You don't have to close the question or so. Maybe I am just misinterpreting your question. Perhaps someone else can help better.

Ok. Re the projector: I think it's obvious that $P$ cannot be diagonal in the eigenbasis. But anything else is highly questionable b/c how on earth could question select a different basis? (that means I would even start to try to construct it)

Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. As I said, I don't know if such a $P$ exists...I haven't tried it anything.

The first operator looks like $\rho = \sum_n p_n |n\rangle\langle n|$ with $p_n > 0$. The second one has the same form with $q_n$ replacing $p_n$. So $P$ would be diagonal with entries $\sqrt{q_n/p_n}$ which is not a projector. Let's assume $P$ is not diagonal, so there is a diagonal projector $Q$ that can be rotated into $P$. So 1. we introduce temperature dependent projectors; 2. we find some other temperature dependent basis in which $Q$ now describing the measurement becomes diagonal. That is so strange that I tend to believe in your statement "does not make sense".
